# Solution for Visual Studio shows message "Error while trying tu run project:" after un signing assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, code-signing

a couple of days ago I signed my assemblies to test ClickOnce deployment.
All worked fine until I cannot deserialize my old binary-serialized-files, so I had to revert the code-signing of the assemblies. That's ok, I will not use ClickOnce, it was just a test.

The problem now is that Visual Studio shows the message "Error while trying to run project:" (whithout giving any more information about why that happens and with that very annoyig sound) when starting to debug. Then I must try again and the debug starts as usual unless, of course, you edit the code.

Is there a solution for that appart from re-installing VS?
Note: I tried deleting the .SUO file but the problem persists.

Comment: We need a screenshot of that sound to narrow this down.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and it's been driving me insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The problem was that, after removing code signing (uncheck the signing options on the project properties), there was .pfx file remaining.

Just deleting that .pfx file stops the "Error while trying to run project" message.

Answer (score 0):

Error comes because recently you might have un-installed Internet Browsers.
       This error will come Because of not assigning the default Browser for the project.
In Visual Studio,Right click on the Project and set Internet Explorer as your Default Browser.